# Let $f$ be an entire. Show that, if $f(z_n) \to \infty$ for all sequences $z_n$ such that $z_n \to \infty$, then f must be a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$. Show that, if $f(z_n) \to \infty$ for all sequences $z_n$ such that $z_n \to \infty$, then f must be a non-constant polynomial.

Since $\lim_{z \to 0}f(\frac{1}{z})=\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\infty$ Thus $f(1/z)$ has a pole of some order. Thus the Taylor';s series of $f(z)$ had to be finite otherwise it would be an essential singularity. Thus $f$ is a polynomial. IS this correct?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: You are using that if $f$ had an essential singularity at $z$, then for any $w\in\mathbb{C}$ there would need to be a sequence $z_n\to z$ such that $f(z_n)\to w$. This can't happen by your assumption so $f$ must have a removable singularity or a singularity of finite order?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Exactly,  one of the way of defining a pole is that limit to a singularity is infinity. If it was removable, the value would be constant if it was a pole infinity if essential the limit would not exist.

Comment: why do we look at $f(1/z)$ instead of $1/f(z)$?